# Add Array Textbox to jquery and pass to ajax and add to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to an array textbox that will pass to jquery and pass to ajax to store in database.

the textbox array will pass to the jquery function then it will send to ajax to another page to store in database

[image]

```
   <div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="personnel[]" style="padding:6px; border-radius:4px; border: none; width:400px;" placeholder="Add Name">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Preview

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields    = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button    = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="personnel[]"  style="padding:6px; border-radius:4px; border: none; width:400px; margin-top:5px;" placeholder="Add Name"><a href="#" class="remove_field"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Remove</button</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});

function preview(){
  var personnel = $('#personnel').val();

$.ajax({url: "travel_preview.php", data: { personnel:personnel }, type: "POST", success: function(result){
           $('#myPreview').modal("show");
           $('.preview_details').html(result);

           }});

}
</script>
```

Comment: What is the issue you are getting?

Comment: i cant get the right code to pass the array textbox to ajax to database

Comment: you can use `.each()`

Comment: have you tried JSON.stringify()?, since you're passing an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map` to retrieve all array input data as below.

**Note** : Add field and enter value what every you want, and then click on **GET DATA** button to print value in console

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields    = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button    = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="personnel[]"  style="padding:6px; border-radius:4px; border: none; width:400px; margin-top:5px;" placeholder="Add Name"><a href="#" class="remove_field"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Remove</button</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});

function preview(){
  //var personnel = $('#personnel').val();
  var personnel = $("input[name='mytext[]']")
              .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
  
  console.log(personnel);

$.ajax({url: "travel_preview.php", data: { personnel:personnel }, type: "POST", success: function(result){
           $('#myPreview').modal("show");
           $('.preview_details').html(result);

           }});

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
     <button type="button" onclick="preview()"> GET DATA </button>
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="personnel[]" style="padding:6px; border-radius:4px; border: none; width:400px;" placeholder="Add Name">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

please add submit button and use form tag to save data into database

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submit-button-id').on('click', function () {
           var personnel = $('#personnel').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "travel_preview.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: $("#form_id").serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.code == '1') {
                         $('#myPreview').modal("hide");
                        $("#myPreview").find('input[type=text]').val('');
                        alert(data.message,'success');

                    } else {
                       alert(data.message, 'error');
                    }
                }
            });
//In php use foreach 
foreach ($_Post['personnel'] as $personnel) {
}
```